# geolocation yahoo maps api

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, yahoo-api, yahoo-maps

i'm trying to get coordinates from geolocation for use in my yahoo map.i had run it in firefox, chrome and internet explorer version 12.0, 18.0.1025.168 m and 9.0.8112.16421. In firefox it asks for permission to share my location(i accept), internet explorer it doesn't support geolocation and chrome supports its but not find the location. here is my code

```
<div id="map" align="right" height="50%" width="50%"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.maps.yahoo.com/ajaxymap?v=3.8&appid=xoo5uJLV34FTpTmoqrs.mIQOX_DTcBhPowcz17ClEeb.jCIZ1Z6_Aa9FO8brGg--"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

alert("ok ws dame");
if(navigator.geolocation) {
    alert("Great..Geolocation API is supported.");
    var map = new YMap(document.getElementById('map')); 
    map.addTypeControl(); 
    map.setMapType(YAHOO_MAP_REG);

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(foundlocation,nolocation);

    function foundlocation(position){
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    alert(latitude+","+longitude);
    var coords = new YGeoPoint(latitude,Longitude);
    map.drawZoomAndCenter(coords,3);
    map.addMarker(coords);
    }
    function nolocation(error){
var map = new YMap(document.getElementById('map')); 
map.addTypeControl(); 
map.setMapType(YAHOO_MAP_REG);
    alert("Location not found.");
    // Display the map centered on a geocoded location
    map.drawZoomAndCenter("Patras", 3);
    var Lat = 38.2444444;
    var Lon = 21.7344444;
    var myPoint = new YGeoPoint(Lat,Lon);
    map.addMarker(myPoint);     
    }
}
else {
var map = new YMap(document.getElementById('map')); 
map.addTypeControl(); 
map.setMapType(YAHOO_MAP_REG);
    alert("Geolocation API is not supported in your browser.");
    // Display the map centered on a geocoded location
    map.drawZoomAndCenter("Patras", 3);
    var Lat = 38.2444444;
    var Lon = 21.7344444;
    var myPoint = new YGeoPoint(Lat,Lon);
    map.addMarker(myPoint);
}
</script>
```

in case of   (navigator.geolocation)   returns false then it shows corectly the deafault position on the map.This works the same in function(nolocation). My problem is when i get the current location.I had put alert messages under navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(foundlocation,nolocation); and inside function(foundlocation) it never shows the message. any help appreciate..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works fine. basicly sometimes it works and some others it doesnt. i dont know why but the code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

your error:var coords = new YGeoPoint(latitude,Longitude);

longitude NOT Longitude with Uppercase "L"

works fine then!!

Comment: ok..that is propably one mistake. but it doesnt get there..there is a problem before that..

Comment: That's the way geolocation works even the examples in w3schools don't work every time.

Comment: yes it works sometimes but i want it to works every time. maybe it's networks problem but the code its just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I use the "new Y.Map()" instead of "new YMap()".Maybe the same effect.